# How to Retrieve array key values in Tcl

Tags: arrays, tcl

Given Data

```
array set color {a red b green c blue}
set keylist [array names $color]
pointlist  {{1 2 3 4} {5 6 7 8} {9 10 11 12} {13 14 15 16}}
```

I get a new list after running a procedure.

```
 newlist  {b b b b}     # Note: length of newlist is same as length of pointlist
```

Question is : when i run a loop these values of b should be substituted, for example in this green.

```
for {set i 0} { $i < [llength $pointlist]} {incr i } {
    lassign [lindex $pointlist $i] x1 y1 x2 y2
    APICommand -points "$x1,$y1,$x2,$y2" -color $color($keylist)
}
```

Now this $color($keylist) is not getting me correct result and errors out saying : 
can't read "color(red blue green)": no such element in array

Instead I want the first set of 4 points to get the green color which is the value of b. Similarly next set of 4 points from pointlist should also get green as its value is also b.

```
 #So, after substitution it should look like APIcommand -points 1,2,3,4 -color green ..... so on and so forth
```

Note this will not always be b , it just happens to be in this case.

Need solution asap. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need `$color([lindex $newlist $i])`

Comment: I was trying to use a foreach loop inside the for loop and then use      -color [lindex $color($newlist) $i] and that is why it was giving me error. but using the array name first and then the index of keylist solved my problem. Thanks again !! (It's exactly what I was looking for )

Answer (score 1):

When iterating across a list, the `foreach` command is useful. It can also be used to iterate over multiple corresponding lists. Assuming `newlist` holds the colors that correspond to the points, I might try something like (usual warnings about untested code):

```
foreach point $pointlist new $newlist {
    APICommand -points [join $point ,] -color $color($new)
}
```

Comment: We dont have to calculate foreach point, we have to do this for group of 4 points. means 4 points corresponds to one color